# Nginx SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have two files from the certification service : 
CSR.txt : 
Looks like this :

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
Code
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

and Private Key with same format

I'm trying to set them up on Nginx but I'm always getting this error

```
 failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib)
```

I have renamed file1.txt to domain.crt
and file2.txt to domain_key.key

Comment: You should probably ask this question on serverfault.com. When you do, include the relevant section of your Nginx config

Comment: Is that a different website  ?

Comment: yes, but it is part of the stackexchange network. Stackoverflow is aimed at programming/ coding questions whereas serverfault is geared more towards system administration etc etc

Comment: Oh thanks ! 
Should I delete this thread ?

Comment: `BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST` is the certificate request (which you must have sent to your CA), not the certificate (which it would have sent back to you).

Comment: Hello guys , I got the CRT file and HTTPS is working but it says the the site's identity is not verified.. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

"the site's identity is not verified", this notification appears in Firefox. This means that the ownership of the domain was not verified by a CA or the organzation is not included on the certificate which provide all the information on the certificate. This happen when the type of certificate do only validate the ownership of the domain via email address or meta tag URL.

See: https://www.globalsign.com/ssl/domain-ssl/

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what you are doing, but it looks like you are confusing a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with a real Certificate (CRT).

So, in order to configure your nginx server for SSL/TLS, follow these steps:

- Generate a strong RSA key-pair (`openssl genrsa ...`)
- Generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) (`openssl req -new ...`)
- Send the request to a Certificate Authority (CA)
- Get a signed certificate (CRT) back from your CA

You can then configure your server to use your "server.key" and your "server.crt" files for SSL/TLS encryption.

If you still get a similiar error, try to remove everything **before** `----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----` and **after** `----- END CERTIFICATE -----`.